# Is there any Spring Boot Microservice Registration to get information about all my services, which port they have, names, up/down?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, monitoring, netflix-eureka

I am searching for a solution, to monitor and gather information about all the services we are currently using (like which service uses which port) and if they are up or not. I found Netflix Eureka and wondered, is this what i am looking for, or is there a better way to do that. Obviously i think, there is a way to do it more simple, but i like that there is a GUI-output (with dynamic information like up/down service) and its kinda easy to get started with. But i wondered if some of you could advise me with my problem. I am quiete new with Microservices.

So to sum it up - i need something to monitor and gather informations about all our microservices (in one central place) especially common information like port, name...and if they are up or down, and i was wondering, if i am at the right place with Netflix Eureka.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Eureka is service discovery mechanism. which will show available services when they are up and running and will route request to those services. For component health check for spring boot microservices (considering you are using one) you can use  actuator. You also have the option of Hystrix.